# Отличие между "Например" и "Так"

Tags: значение-слов, вводные-слова

Работаю над своим собственным руководством по Emacs'у. Там у меня есть такой отрывок:

> Кнопка `TAB` индентирует не до ближайшего tab stop'а, а сразу на
> нужную глубину.  Для индентирования до ближайшего tab stop'а можно
> использовать команду `indent-rigidly`. **Так,** `C-u 8 C-x Tab` добавит
> восемь пробелов, а `C-u -4 C-x Tab` удалит четыре.

Почему слово "Например" в начале последнего предложения смотрится (точнее, смотрелось **бы**) немного неестественно? (Это лишь моё субъективное ощущение?)

Иными словами, справедливо ли утверждение, что слово "Например" в начале предложения всегда можно заменить на "Так"? И если это всё же не так, то в чём отличия между их смыслом и употреблении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличия здесь в основном грамматические.

> **наприме́р**
>
> Вводное слово, неизменяемое.
>
> https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80

> **так**
>
> Наречие, определительное, образа или способа действия, также частица,
> союзное слово; неизменяемое.
>
> https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA

Но и некоторые смысловые отличия тоже есть, и они, как им и положено, исходят из смысла слов: вводное слово *например* вводит «пример», то есть конкретный случай/конкретные случаи того, о чём речь до этого шла в общем, а слово *так*, которое, среди прочего, есть определительное, образа или способа действия, демонстрирует, **как**, то есть каким образом действует то, о чём шла речь.

Answer (score 3):

Неестественно такая замена смотрится потому, что вводимые "примеры" буквально не являются частным случаем общего понятия из предшествующего высказывания (в нём нет утверждения, что нажатие кнопки "*добавляет несколько пробелов*"), вследствие чего присоединяемая через "например" конструкция (здесь не имеет значения, что для разгрузки предложения разъединены) вызывает безответный вопрос: "пример чего это?" В исходном же варианте "**так**" означает **"в соответствии с изложенным**, [в приводимых случаях имеет место то-то]", причём грамматического присоединения (как в случае "например") не требуется, что позволяет соотнести примеры не только с предпоследним предложением, но и с содержанием *всего абзаца*, - поэтому всё воспринимаетя естественно. Иными словами, "например" грамматически более конкретно (ссылается на общее понятие буквально), чем "так" (ссылается на описанную ситуацию в целом).